# winhttp-proxy-resolver command line switch not working in CefSharp

Tags: cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

CEF supports the command line chromium switch "--winhttp-proxy-resolver" which automatically fetches the PAC script configuration from Windows proxy settings and resolves the proxy server details. However by passing this switch to CefSharp doesn't automatically fetch the PAC script configuration from Windows proxy settings.

I tested this flag via below methods, but none of the methods are working.

> settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("winhttp-proxy-resolver");
> settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("winhttp-proxy-resolver", "1");

I would expect CefSharp to support all command line switches supported by CEF/Chromium.

Please advise how to use this switch in CefSharp

Comment: `CefSharp` supports the same arguments as `CEF` when comparing the **exact** same version. How are you testing `CEF` exactly? Are you comparing **exactly** the same version? Load `chrome://version` in `CefSharp` and `CEF` to compare the versions and command line args.

Comment: We are using almost latest versions on both. This command line option is several years old. I was troubleshooting this issue, still not able to come up with solution. I am initializing & launching the CefBrowser process from user process, and using Cefsharp.offscreen, so don't have privilege to run chrome://version. Do we need any additional permission for the user process where CefBrowser is being created ?

Comment: I am getting only these logs related to proxy in verbose logging 
VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(191)] 4A1AC000: set chrome proxy config service to 4A060000
WARNING:policy_logger.cc(148)]:components\enterprise\browser\controller\chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(88) Could not create policy manager as CBCM is not enabled.

Comment: Are you comparing the exact same version? You can still load `chrome://version`, either take a screen shot or open `DevTools` and review the page.

Comment: I am able to resolve this and found the root cause of the issue. Our Cefsharp offscreen app runs as Windows Service under the Local System Account. In windows, proxy settings is set at account level, not at the machine level. I had to set the proxy settings in the Local system account compared to actual user account to make this chromium flag work. Also I am using the use-system-proxy-resolver instead of winhttp-proxy-resolver, as the later is deprecated and will be removed in future per the chromium documentation. Thanks for your time @amaitland

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this and found the root cause of the issue. Our Cefsharp offscreen app runs as Windows Service under the Local System Account. In windows, proxy settings is set at account level, not at the machine level. I had to set the proxy settings in the Local system account compared to actual user account to make this chromium flag work. Also I am using the use-system-proxy-resolver instead of winhttp-proxy-resolver, as the later is deprecated and will be removed in future per the chromium documentation.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/net/docs/proxy.md#winhttp_proxy_resolver-command-line-switch